# How can I define a Static Resource in C# instead of XAML?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
   <Color x:Key="WordTextColor">#2196f3</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>

<Grid>
   <Grid.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="Grid">
         <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource WordTextColor}" />
      </Style>
```

How can I code this in C#

Also can I code up this Static Resource as a string instead of a Color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a helper class, like this, where you define all your colors / values

```cs
public static class Styles
{
    private static Color _backgroundColor = Color.FromHex("151515");
    public static Color BackgroundColor => _backgroundColor;
}
```

Then, in xaml, you reference it in the header:

```xml
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourProjectAssembly.YourName;assembly=YourProjectAssembly.YourName"
```

And to use it:

```xml
<Grid BackgroundColor="{x:Static local:Styles.BackgroundColor}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Color can be set in String values instead of Hexa values.
Resources can be set in Window.Resources or Grid.Resources.

**Resources in Window level**

```
<Window.Resources>
   <Color x:Key="TheBackgroundColor">#2196f3</Color>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
  <Style TargetType="Grid">
     <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource TheBackgroundColor}" />
  </Style>
</Grid>
```

**Resources in Grid level**

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
     <Color x:Key="TheBackgroundColor">#2196f3</Color>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="Grid">
     <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource TheBackgroundColor}" />
  </Style>
</Grid>
```